# How to parse jade to plain text?

Tags: pug

I am creating an html message in node.js with jade. Proper html message should also contain plain text version. It would be nice to convert the same template to plain text. Is it possible?

***Note:*** I am sorry for not being clear. I have created a jade template that produced a perfect html document. I do not have issues with jade template. I want to use the same template to produce a plain text document with the sample layout, but without html tags. Is there a renderer that can generate plain text document from jade template?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [The pipe character `|` is the syntax for inserting plain text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you require this to be done on client side or is it in Node? Just take the rendered HTML output and throw it through a html->text converter (doing it directly from jade isn't worth the effort)

A quick google produced https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text

If you need it client side, you could probably use browserify or something.

Comment: Yes, this is an option. But jade format looks so generic that I though it could be rendered into plain text directly. But I did not find a different renderer and it seems there is none.

Comment: Maybe there is another modeling language that can be rendered into both - html and plain text in node?

Comment: Not that I know of, but passing it through the html to text parser should still be the best bang for your buck.  I can't imagine anything easier than `var text = htmlToText.fromString(jade.render(myJadeFile))`